# Create facebook application page which can visited as http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=appid

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps

I have created a facebook apps. Works fine for me. It contains canvas url, visit as `http://apps.facebook.com/{something}`, But I want to create a application which can be visited as `http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id={appid}` and alos contain a link `Add to My Page` options. I cant create it. I dont know what can I do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to advanced settings and click create community page

see http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/